# An array of LPWSTR pointers, not working right

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Declare:

```
LPWSTR** lines= new LPWSTR*[totalLines];
```

then i set using:

```
lines[totalLines]=&totalText;
SetWindowText(totalChat,(LPWSTR)lines[totalLines]);
totalLines++;
```

Now I know totalText is right, cause if i SetWindowText using totalText it works fine. I need the text in totalLines too.

I'm also doing:

```
//accolating more memory.

  int orgSize=size;
  LPWSTR** tempArray;
  if (totalLines == size) { 
   size *= 2; 
   tempArray = new LPWSTR*[size]; 
   memcpy(tempArray, lines,sizeof(LPWSTR)*orgSize); 
   delete [] lines; 
    lines = tempArray; 
  }
```

to allocate more memory when needed.

My problem is that the lines is not getting the right data. It works for the first time around then it get corrupted. I thought at first i was overwriting but totalLines is increase. Hopefully this is enough information.

Comment: Any reason you're not using vector? You can get the buffer by `&vec[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LPWSTR` is already [a pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355%28PROT.10%29.aspx), so you're creating a 2D array of pointers - is that what you wanted? I think not, because this:

```
SetWindowText(totalChat,(LPWSTR)lines[totalLines]);
```

Casts `LPWSTR*` to `LPWSTR`. Isn't your compiler complaining?

Comment: The compiler probably was complaining, and the cast was probably a misguided attempt to shut it up.  Alas.

Comment: What I want to be able to hold lines of text. Such as

lines[0]="Hello"
lines[1]="Welcome"
lines[2]="Test"

and such. What i'm trying to do is create a simple chat program, and i'm wanting to hold the text in a array like that so i can simply code a scroll bar. Sorry, I should of mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Alas- Your right, but i'm not trying to even use SetWindowText like that. I was just doing that to help explain the question.

Comment: Eli is right, you only need a LPWSTR*, not a pointer-to-pointer-to-LPWSTR.

Comment: What, i could of swear i tryed that first. Grrr, Yea, it works fine now. Thanks Alot guys.

Answer (score 0):

These two statements:

```
LPWSTR** lines= new LPWSTR*[totalLines];
lines[totalLines]=&totalText;
```

invoke undefined behavior. The problem is that the maximum index of an array `totalLines` long is `totalLines-1`.

If you'd post what exactly you were trying to accomplish we might be able to help better. For example, it seems this problem could be much better solved with a `std::vector<std::vector<wchar_t> >` or `std::vector<std::basic_string<wchar_t> >` rather than an explicitly allocated array of `LPWSTR`s.

Comment: LPWSTR** lines= new LPWSTR*[totalLines]; has been changed to LPWSTR** lines= new LPWSTR*[size]; Sorry, i changed that before i posted this question but forgot to update the question.

Comment: You could just use `std::wstring` so you don't need to specify the template parameters to `basic_string`.

Comment: @GMan: Yep. I was just lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben and Eli I have my answer. It should be LPWSTR* lines= new LPWSTR[size]; since LPWSTR is already a pointer. Thanks guys.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::vector`? :( Bunnies are sad.